# Need information about file safety

Tags: php, html

Hello stackoverflow community! I've got question about website security! I'm new in creating TVS so I want to ask you about this include file stuff. Let's say, I've got index.php file which has: `include_once 'style/header.php';` and the file header.php contains:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Some title!</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script type="text/JavaScript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link rel="Shortcut Icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />
    </head>
    <body>
```

So if some one will try to directly access header.php he will see html tags. How can I block access to included file or encrypt them? Or maby there is other stuff what programmers do?

Comment: Maybe you could declare a variable (before the include code) with a specific value, then in header.php you check the value of that variable, if it's not the right value, you run a `die()` or similar?

Comment: Move included/required files outside of your web directories

Comment: You can simply move them to a directory and use a .htaccess file to prevent other to have access on it via http requests

Comment: Thanx for ideas! @DanielLisik i will try your idea!

Comment: This is somewhat pointless. Direct access to a »partial template« (without any processing logic or any feasibility to leak interna) isn't a *security* issue by itself. It might get indexed by search engines, which is undesirable, but apart from that, there's no need to obfuscate or hide this very sample code.

Comment: @mario so if that could would be like variable php, it can get indexed?

Answer (score 1):

you can insert this line of code at the start of your header file

```
<?php if(strtolower(__FILE__) == strtolower(realpath(".".$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']))) { die("direct access is not allowed."); } ?>
```

this will not allow direct access to the file but allow including.